# save .txt file without whitespace after webscraping

Tags: r

This is my code for webscraping with R, which works well.

```
require(httr)
require(rvest)
library(KoNLP)
useSejongDic()


total = c()
site = "http://movie.daum.net/moviedb/grade?
movieId=92107&type=netizen&page="

for( i in 1:10){
    url = paste0(site, i);
    mention = GET(url) %>% read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("p.desc_review") %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    repair_encoding();
    total =  rbind(total, mention);
}


total = gsub("\t","",total)
total = gsub("\n","",total)

text1=extractNoun(total)
noun= sapply(total,extractNoun,USE.NAMES = FALSE)
undata= unlist(noun)
write(undata,"C:\\Users\\dlgof\\DATA.txt")
```

However, there are too many white spaces in the txt file, how can I remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your undata has a lot of " ". Add

```
undata = undata[undata != " "]
```

before you write.